# I want to know how to repeat a process in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print "You've entered a wording system!"
print "What words do you want?"

while False:
    word1 = raw_input('enter your word:')
    word2 = raw_input('enter your word:')

print word1
print word2

if len(word1)>len(word2):
    word_difference = len(word1) - len(word2)
    print word1, "is", word_difference, "letters longer than", word2

elif len(word2)>len(word1):
    word_difference = len(word2) - len(word1)
    print word2, "is", word_difference, "letters longer than", word1

elif len(word1) == len(word2):
    print word1, "has same number of letters as", word2    

repeat = raw_input("Would you like to enter two more words?(y/n)")    

if repeat == "y":
    y == False
```

so I want to create a code that repeat from `word1 = raw input` to `repeat = raw_input(asking fort two more words)` if the question ask you to `"Would you like to enter two more words" is == y` and if `no == Good bye!`

Comment: You've already shown you know how to write a while loop... Why not use another one?

Comment: `while False` will never get executed, since it is, um, not True.

Comment: It looks like all the code should be in the first loop, which should execute as long as `repeat` equals "y" (with `repeat` initialized appropriately prior to the loop).

Comment: `while` loop does exactly what you are trying to do, but you are not using it correctly. I recommend you read the [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) first.

Answer (score 0):

Just put *all* the code in your loop, which iterates as long as `repeat` (initialized to "y" stays equal to "y"):

```
print "You've entered a wording system!"
print "What words do you want?"

repeat = "y"
while repeat == "y":
    word1 = raw_input('enter your word:')
    word2 = raw_input('enter your word:')

    print word1
    print word2

    if len(word1)>len(word2):
        word_difference = len(word1) - len(word2)
        print word1, "is", word_difference, "letters longer than", word2

    elif len(word2)>len(word1):
        word_difference = len(word2) - len(word1)
        print word2, "is", word_difference, "letters longer than", word1

    elif len(word1) == len(word2):
        print word1, "has same number of letters as", word2    

    repeat = raw_input("Would you like to enter two more words?(y/n)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Iterator to iterate and repeat the process. For more information please see the reference link http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook006.html